# Multiprocess Queue in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, queue, fifo

What's a good implementation of a multiprocess queue in Bash?

I was considering a FIFO, with each line representing an element in the queue:

```
mkfifo fifo
ls > fifo
```

In a different process:

```
read element < fifo
```

The expected result is that the reader process reads one line (i. e. one element) and stores it in the variable `$element`, leaving the rest of the queue untouched so that other reader processes can get elements (lines) as well.

Unfortunately this does not work.  The `read` statement opens the FIFO, causing the writer (`ls`) to complete at once, closing the FIFO then seems to cause the remaining data to be dropped, other elements cannot be read by another process (in fact, the next `read < fifo` hangs until another writer appears and writes into the FIFO).

I also considered touching files in a special directory (as a writer) and moving the files away (as a reader), but this seems tedious and obviously is not feasible for millions of queue entries.

Can I get the FIFO variant to work somehow?

Is there a different way of implementing a shell queue, having several writers and several readers, all working on the same queue?

Comment: I'm not really sure that what you want to implement is gonna be trivial and clear with shell and FIFOs. Even considering that you may keep the pipe open at all times so it doesn`t lose the data, like 123 said, the pipe buffer sizes are not really suitable for millions of queue entries (so if readers are slow and the write rate is big, you'll lose data), and synchronizing readers (if needed) may be painful.

Comment: I get the same impression.  In my tests I encountered readers reading a part of a line while the rest of the line was read by another reader (rare occasion, but happens).  I don't know how to avoid this.  But maybe there is a kind of "standard" tool like a small server process which can act as a queue, taking from writers and distributing to readers.  I just don't happen to know such a tool.

Answer (score 2):

I may have found an answer myself.  I'm not using FIFOs but a minimalistic TCP server accepting input from one port and writing output line by line to another.

To set up the TCP server, I use this script:

```
nc -k -l 4444 | while read a
  do echo "$a" | nc -l 4445
done
```

(Append `&` to run this in the background, of course.)

Then the writers can do sth like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<10000; i++))
do
  printf "x%02d\n" "$i"
done >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444
```

and the readers can do sth like this:

```
while ! { read a < /dev/tcp/localhost/4445; } 2>/dev/null
do
  sleep 2  # we poll; if there is nothing, we sleep between polls
done
echo "$a"
```

This script fetches *one* element (line) and processes it (`echo "$a"`).  Do this in a loop if you want to drain the queue.

I'm not all too happy with the polling solution, but tests show that it works reliably with two writers and two readers (and I don't see why more readers and writers should pose a problem).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep the PIPE open

```
$mkfifo PIPE
$cat > PIPE &
```

Pipe is now open indefinitely until you kill the cat.

```
$ls > PIPE &
$read Line < PIPE
$echo $Line
 file1
```

You can now write and read to your hearts content.

Comment: This seems to work with the minimal example, but *my* `ls` (which is more complex, of course, e. g. `for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do echo $i; done`) receives a SIGPIPE and aborts using this.

Comment: @Alfe That loop works for me, how are you running it/writing to the pipe ?

Comment: My writer tries this: `cat > fifo & catpid=$!; (for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do echo $i; done > fifo) &` and dies from a SIGPIPE when a reader does this: `declare -i c; c=0; while sleep 0.1$RANDOM; do read a < fifo; c+=1; echo "$a $c"; done`.